# How to define one to many relationship only on the dependent entity and make it required

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem with the configuration of the one-to-many relationship in ef core 2.2. 
I have the following scenario (entities are different, but this is not relevant). The issue is:

This class already exist in the code base, and I can't touch it

```cs
public class Order : Entity {
//    public ICollection<OrderLine> Orders; // I would like to have it but I don't and I can't
}
```

I need to add this class:

```cs
public class OrderLine: Entity {
    public Order Order { get; set; } //I have only this
}
```

I need some technical advise. I've written the configuration for the class:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OrderLine> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x=>x.Id);
    builder.Property(x=>x.Order).IsRequired();
}
```

This unfortunately gives me the following error while adding the migration:

> The property 'Order.OrderLine' is of type 'OrderLine' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

When I delete the line : `builder.Property(x=>x.Order).IsRequired();` the field becomes nullable which is not acceptable.

I used the following trick:

```cs
builder.Ignore(x => x.Order);
builder.HasOne<Order>().WithMany().IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

But then when I set the Order field when constructing OrderLine, I get the exception on saving to database, because the OrderId gets default value (it is ignored). Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `OrderLine` class.

```cs
public class OrderLine: Entity 
{
    public int Id {get;set;} // EF requires primary key, remove if it is declared in Entity base class
    public int OrderId {get;set;} //Foreign Key

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; } // Navigational Property for eager and lazy loading. it should be virtual
}
```

And No need to provide fluent configuration, by convention it will create one to many relationships, and OrderLine must have referenceing OrderId set.

Comment: Are you sure this will cause the migration with required: true?

Comment: This approach has two drawbacks: id to referenced entity is a persistence-related concept leaking to the domain model, which is not clean from the domain-driven-design perspective. The second issue is that you have to ignore Order property in the entity configuration in order to avoid duplicate foreign key column in the table. This also means, that you will have to  set OrderId manually because the Order property is ignored - and that is also something I wanted to avoid to keep my domain model clean from persistence-related concept. (To the extent I can). Nevertheless thank you for your help.

Comment: @Marcin it will not create duplicate foreign key. And you need not set OrderId manually. if you are adding Order & OrderLine as graph EF will take care of the relationship and update OrderId after SaveChanges. if you don't want anyone to use the OrderId column you can decorate with [Obsolete] attribute. If you found any other appropriate answer please post here.